# Node Red - Accessing dashboard from remote server

Tags: remote-access, dashboard, node-red

I have a question regarding the Node Red dashboard. I've got my dashboard all set up and working. Now, I want to be able to access the dashboard outside of my local network. Right now I do this through a VNC server. What needs to happen next is that clients need to able to access the dashboard, but they are not getting access to my VNC server of course. I have done my fair amount of Google work. I (somewhat) understand that a service like ngrok (ngrok.com) or dataplicity (dataplicity.com) is what I am looking for. What would be the best way of setting this up *safely*?

Might be useful to clarify: I'm using a raspberry Pi!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the outside world access to your dashboard, you can also consider to host your node-red application in the cloud.  See links at the bottom-left of page https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/
Most of those services have a free tier - so it might you cost nothing.

If you cannot deploy your complete node-red in the cloud (e.g. because it is reading local sensors) then you can split your node-red application into 2 node-red applications: one running locally and one (with the dashboard) running in the cloud.  Of course then the 2 node-red applications need to exchange messages: for this the cloud services mentioned on that page also provides a secure way to send and receive events from the node-red cloud application that you can use.